# How can I add a typed property to the window object in a module?

Tags: typescript, window, global, browserify, tsify

I currently have a file `main.ts` with code as follows:

```
import Game from './game';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        game: Game;
        throttleScreenResizeRender: number;
        resizeTimeout: number;
    }
}

 ...

window.throttleScreenResizeRender = 0;
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to get the Window typings in a separate file to avoid code duplication. My current attempt looks like this:

```
// window.d.ts

import Game from './game';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        game: Game;
        throttleScreenResizeRender: number;
        resizeTimeout: number;
    }
}
```

and:

```
// main.ts

import Game from './game';
import 'interfaces/window';

window.throttleScreenResizeRender = 0;
```

This gives me a `Error TS2339: Property 'throttleScreenResizeRender' does not exist on type 'Window'.` on compilation.

I'm using Typescript version 2.0.3

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

I'm using Browserify with tsify as indicated by [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html). This is my gulp file:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserify = require("browserify");
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const tsify = require("tsify");

...

gulp.task('tsify', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['src/main.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath));
});
```

Relevant `packages.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
    "tsify": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? with `1.8.10` and `2.0.3` it seems to be working fine for me. Are you sure that this is the exact code you're trying to compile?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.3

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's the exact code.

Comment: I works well for me, the only difference is that I don't have the game module. Maybe try to add `export {};` in your `window.d.ts`?

Comment: Not working either... even if I remove the import and export from window.d.ts and declare game as any, turning it into a script...

Comment: You must have an import/export to make it a module. But as I wrote, I can't reproduce it. It would be good if you could share a sample that reproduces your problem

Comment: That's all the relevant code, really. Maybe it's related to me running it with tsify? I've updated the question with this. I'll also try to get an example that runs tsc from the terminal...

Comment: I've never worked with `tsify`, but it shouldn't matter, it uses `tsc`. But you can test it yourself, just run `tsc` yourself and see if you get that error or not

Comment: This actually works when running this code isolated, with tsc. Maybe it's a problem with my gulp file, or my tsconfig.json...

Comment: It's not a problem with your `tsconfig.json`, otherwise `tsc` wouldn't have worked as well. It's either webpack or gulp

Comment: The import paths in your question don't look right. If `window.d.ts` imports `Game` from `./game`, it must be in the same directory. However, `main.ts` imports `Game` from `./game` and imports `interfaces/window`. What is `interfaces/window`? Is that just a typo in your question? Also, you should include your `tsconfig.json` in your question. (It's unfortunate that your question was not tagged with `tsify` when you first posted it. I'm a maintainer and would have seen this a lot sooner.)